# Fields initialization in Java like in C#

Tags: java, c#

Doesn't java allow fields initialization like C# does?

```
   public class MyClass {
     public String var1;
     public String var2;
     public String var3;
   }

   //.........

   String myVar1 = //....
   String myVar2 = //....
   String myVar3 = //....
   return new MyClass { // doesn't work in Java
      var1 = myVar1,
      var2 = myVar2,
      var3 = myVar3
   };
```

I think I've read about somewhere. But I can't find it because fields initialization seems to be a different thing.

Comment: "like C# does" - what do you mean by this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Java doesn't allow that. The Java syntax doesn't provide an equivalent . You can go closer to that initializing an anonymous class but it is not the same thing .

So the real answer is Java doesn't support field initialization, but does support anonymous class instantiation that C# doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't java allow fields initialization like C# does

yes it does .

but this

```
 return new MyClass { // doesn't work in Java
      var1 = myVar1,
      var2 = myVar2,
      var3 = myVar3
   };
```

is not field initialization it's called object initialization in C# , java doesn't provide such a syntax.

Comment: @aleroot read the complete answer

Comment: Yes, but the first part is wrong

Comment: @aleroot is class X{ int i = 5; } not field initialization

Comment: No, Java doesn't support field initialization like c# does. Read my answer or documentation.

Comment: oh my god, @aleroot, ok, it doesnt. 
Ramanlfc ok, it does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in java. But in java 8, you can simulate like c# object initialization. First define a function like this.

```
    public static <T, R> R apply(final T t, final Function<T, R> function) {
        return function.apply(t);
    }
```

Then apply like this.

```
    final McTrack track = Util.apply(new McTrack(), mcTrack -> {
        mcTrack.setArea(Util.apply(new Area(), area -> {
            area.setId(1L);
            area.setName("Dhaka South");
            area.setRegion(Util.apply(new Region(), region -> {
                region.setId(1L);
                region.setName("Dhaka");
                return region;
            }));
            return area;
        }));
        mcTrack.setId(1L);
        mcTrack.setDate(new Date());
        return mcTrack;
    });
```

I have found it quiet useful.